# Finding Mouse Position relative to a panel

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, mouse-position

I'm trying to get the mouse's position within a panel, as in the top left of the panel = x/y 0,0.

What I have at the minute gives the position on the entire screen, so depending on where the panel (which is in a frame) is on the screen, the coordinates are different. I guess you could add to the x/y co-ordinates to account for this, but this seems like a messy solution. Can anyone help?

Here's the mouseListener I'm using, which has been added to the panel.

```
private class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter 
{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        // Finds the location of the mouse
        PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point b = a.getLocation();

        // Gets the x -> and y co-ordinates
        int x = (int) b.getX();
        int y = (int) b.getY();
        System.out.println("Mouse x: " + x);
        System.out.println("Mouse y: " + y);

        // Determines which tile the click occured on
        int xTile = x/tileSize;
        int yTile = y/tileSize;

        System.out.println("X Tile: " + xTile);
        System.out.println("Y Tile: " + yTile);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [MouseEvent.getPoint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getPoint%28%29).

> Returns the x,y position of the event *relative to the source component.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MouseEvent.getX()` and `MouseEvent.getY()` to get the relative co-ordinates of X & Y respectively.

```
int relativeX = e.getX();
int relativeY = e.getY();
...
```